# InterlockedCompareExchangePointer takes the wrong type?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

This function is comparing and exchanging the pointer itself but takes a pointer to volatile data rather than taking a volatile pointer. Can it really be this wrong? do I need to use #ifdef and InterlockedCompareExchange[64] instead? Or I am misunderstanding somehow?

Comment: [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683568.aspx) says it takes `PVOID volatile *` - that's a pointer to a volatile pointer, as it should be. It makes no sense to make the parameter itself `volatile` - it's a local variable not shared between threads. The `PVOID` pointer `Destination` points to - the one being exchanged - is what is properly marked `volatile`.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I must be missing something.

Comment: I would suggest using [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) for this purpose if you can, it will handle all of this under the covers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types are correct. In your head you can change the `PVOID` type to something else and it should make more sense, `(SIZE_T volatile *, SIZE_T, SIZE_T)` etc.